# Magento get stock quantity at related products, upsells, crosssells in frontend

Tags: magento

I need to get the stock quantity for each product in the section where "Related products" is showed in frontend. Using Magento 1.9.

This function will not help me show the actual qty in my related products section:

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

The function shows stock *qty* in the product view page and the catalog collection but does not work for related products.
What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are actually calling the above piece of code inside a PHTML file.

**Assuming** you are using the RWD theme and calling it inside a PHTML directly (which is not as per Magento Standards), the file location would be **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml**

Inside, the **FOREACH** loop, call the below piece of code (screenshot attached for reference - frontend display):

`<?php echo Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_item)->getQty(); ?>`

The ideal solution would be overriding the CORE file:

`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php`

like below:

`app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Stock/Item.php`

in order to add a new function:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_CatalogInventory_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
{
    public function getItemStockQty($product)
    {
        return $this->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
    }
}
```

And inside the PHTML file, under the **FOREACH LOOP** call this function as below:

`<?php echo $this->getItemStockQty($_item); ?>`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I hope I can help you someday.